# Store conditional forwarder in Active Directory

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

When creating a conditional forwarder in DNS, what does the option *Store this conditional forwarder in Active Directory* do? What happens if the option is not enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing that conditional forwarder in Active Directory lets it propagate out to the other Domain Controllers either in the domain or the forest.  This way if you need to change one of the remote DNS server IP addresses you can manage it in one place.  If you do not do this you have to connect to each DNS server and create and/or change the conditional forwarder on each server.

I am sure there are practical reasons to do such a thing (in my instance not checking that box), but in my environment I cannot think of any.  Maybe testing reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This is one scenario, where i have had to use only local storage, usually conditional forwarders are replicated inside the Ad to all DC /DNS servers.

if only part of domain controllers/DNS servers are able to connect to conditional forwarder servers,(due network restrictions) but all Dc servers needs to resolve all names domain names, then only solution is to use local setting, so that those servers that can connect remote DNS servers, use the real target IP addresses, and those servers that can't connect those remote servers, create same conditional forwarder but uses local servers IP addresses, the ones that can connect to remote servers. 
Example:
Server A and B in domain mydomain.com and server C (DNS server) in test.com domain. If only server "A" can connect to conditional forwarder target server C, you can create local conditional forwarder on server A for test.com with target address for server C.
On the server B that can't connect to server C, you create local conditional forwarder for domain test.com, with Ip address of server A, which then knows from where the test.com addresses needs to resolved.

Not the easiest method to keep up, if you have more than few DC/DNS servers in your environmen

Comment: Yes this method is particularly useful if one of your domain controllers is running within an Azure virtual network, and the rest are on-prem, and you want to be able to resolve some names from a Private DNS Zone in Azure that's only accessible from the virtual network.